# How to make the row not repeating properly according the field

Tags: jasper-reports

i have create one statistical report according the gender. 
The field names ***Jantina***.

I have a problem when remove the *Print repeating values*. I just want the field is not repeating according the ***Jantina*** field. But unfortunately the row not repeating all the row without following the ***Jantina***.

How to do that? Anyone got the idea?

This is my jrxml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="penyata_bulanan_ikut_negeri_jantina_test" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="bulan" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Integer(-1)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="tahun" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Integer(-1)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="negeri" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Integer(00)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="jantina" class="java.lang.Long">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Long(2)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT @row := @row + 1 as r,bulan,tahun,negeri,jantina,
bilmale,jds,jumall,
ROUND(CAST((bilmale*100 /(jumall))AS DECIMAL(7,3)),2) as percent,
ROUND(CAST((jds*100 /(jumall))AS DECIMAL(7,3)),2) as p_jdk,
countstate
FROM some_table
group by date_format(X.createDate,'%Y' ),date_format(X.createDate,'%M' ),X.male,X.state
order by 1 asc) as a,(select @row := 0) as r]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="r" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="bulan" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="tahun" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="negeri" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="jantina" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="bilmale" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="jds" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="jumall" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="percent" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="p_jdk" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="countstate" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <sortField name="bulan"/>
    <sortField name="tahun"/>
    <sortField name="negeri"/>
    <sortField name="jantina"/>
    <group name="bulan">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{bulan}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band/>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <group name="jantina">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{jantina}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="48" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="237" y="10" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Penyata bulanan]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[negeri]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="79" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[jantina]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="158" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[bilmale]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="237" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[jds]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="316" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[percent]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="395" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[p_jdk]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="474" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[countstate]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{negeri}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="79" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{jantina}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="158" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{bilmale}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="237" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{jds}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="316" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{percent}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="395" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{p_jdk}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="474" y="0" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Long"><![CDATA[$F{countstate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you have and what do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is i create the group and put this formula in 
"Print When Expression" into field. That is new Boolean($V{negeri_COUNT}.intValue()==1)
and i uncheck "Print Repeated values "